# Does "recursive" mean the same in "recursive functions" and in definition of Fibonacci function?

Tags: computer-science, recursion, computability

Why are [recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function#Definition) called "recursive"?  Does "recursive" mean that we can define a family of functions inductively (from primitive recursive functions to composite recursive functions)?

Some functions can be defined recursively in terms of themselves individually. For example, [Fibonacci function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), and many functions which have been implemented in programming languages by divide and conquer. What is such a function called? Also "recursive" function?

Do the uses of "recursive" in the above two scenarios have related meanings at all?

Comment: IMO, the origin is Deutsch: [rekursive](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rekursion#Rekursive_Definition_einer_Funktion_und_Untertypen_von_Rekursion). [Dedekind (1888)](https://archive.org/details/wassindundwasso00dedegoog/page/n56/mode/2up) codified the *Indictive Definition* (Definition durch Induction, Th.126). I think that this kind of def was named "rekursive"  by [Hilbert](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-3-540-69444-1%2F1.pdf) and [Skolem (1923)](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA302)

Comment: Originally *recursive* named the class of *primitive recursive*. Later, with Godel (1933) the *general* recursive function concept emerged as distinct from the primitive one.

Comment: Thus, in conclusion, *recursive function* means an arithmetical function defined inductively.

Answer (score 1):

In the link you refer to $\mu$-recursive functions, also partial recursive functions. Indeed, these functions are defined from the base functions (successor function, projections functions, zero functions of each arity) by applying a finite sequence of compositions, primitive recursions and minimalizations. This is the class of computable functions by the Church thesis. This concept belongs to computability theory.

The Fibonacci function can be defined by recursion (calling itself several times to get a result). This concept belongs to programming.

Comment: Thanks. What does "This concept belongs to programming" mean? Do the uses of "recursive" in the above two scenarios have related meanings at all?

Comment: One can show that the Fibonacci function can be defined as primitive recursive function. So in computability its just an example of a primitive recursive function.

Comment: How do you call functions which can be defined in terms of themslves? Are such functions always "recursive functions" in computability theory, and even primitive recursive functions?

Comment: In programming, functions that are defined by themselves have a recursive definition. But in computability, primitive recursion is just one concept besides composition and minimalization. For instance, addition of two natural numbers can be defined by primitive recursion.